# MsAccess: Subform requery from another subform not updating

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, subforms

I have a form called frmMain that has two subforms. frmUserRole and frmTraining.

The frmUserRole subform has a combobox the result of which I use to run in a query to generate training results in the frmTraining subform which has a single control called TrainingModule.

The frmTraining subform has a recordsource of the training query which as I mentioned before has a field referencing the combobox value.

### Events

I have simple requery event connected to the on-change event in the combobox the logic being, if you change the value in the combobox, then the new value will automatically be used to update the query and populate the frmTraining subform with the new results.

The syntax I am using for the combobox on-change event is

[Forms]![frmMain]!frmTraining.Form.Requery

### What is not happening

The subform is not updating with the new query results.

What is happening.

If I go to the frmTraining subform and press F5 the new values come through indicating that everything is operating except the actual requery.

If I put a msgbox on the on-change event it is triggered so I know the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the syntax you have used before. Here's the syntax I have previously used

`Me![frmTraining].requery`

And

`forms!frmMain.form![FrmTraining].requery`.

> EDIT

I would set the training subform query criteria to `forms!frmMain![frmUserRole]![combobox].column(0)` on the related field.

I would then do the requery `forms!frmMain.form!frmTraining.requery` on the afterupdate of the frmUserRole subform combobox. I say `afterUpdate` because I believe there can be issues with `onChange`

Comment: Thanks LiamH. Your format is definitely more succinct and I guess I should get in the habit of referencing the current object rather than using absolute references, however I know the format I am using still works so there is some other issue that is causing the requery not to work. Oh and I am referencing from a subform so I would need to use Me.parent!controlName wouldn't I (control name being subform2).

Comment: I have re-read your question and I think I fully understand what it is you want to achieve. What is the combobox field called?

Comment: LiamH. The combobox in the calling frmUserRole subform is UserRole. I did not mention the called subforms control which is actually a textbox called Training Module. I tell you if this site could allow attachments it would make things a whole lot easier but still appreciate the help from you and the site.

Comment: Thanks Liam. But that did not work either. After spending the better part of another 2 hours on this I did stumble on the answer I just do not know why. If i add a main form refresh after the requery (in the userrole subform it works. This is odd to say the least.